# Use a "Friendly" Label on Drives or Partitions in FreeBSD

Tags: osx, freebsd, dual-boot, disk

Maybe I am missing this and it's really simple, but I cannot figure out how to label a BSD disk.

I have looked at `tunefs` or `gpart` and even `disklabel`, however none do what I am looking for - I don't want to create a label like `\home` or `\var` or anything else that can be mounted, I just  want to give a "friendly name" to the drive or partition.

For example, I have an XServe G4 with 3 *physical*  drives.  One is a dual boot OS X and FreeBSD 10, a OS X Install drive (a copy of the install CD) and finally a FreeBSD 10 USB Install disk.  So, looking at the symbols in the picture from left to right...

- The first (unlabeled) disk is the FreeBSD boot partition on the first disk
- The second (with the USB icon) is a FreeBSD Installation ISO on bootable USB
- The third (Macintosh HD0)is an OS X boot partition on the first disk
- The fourth (Mac OS X Server Install) is a partition on a second disk with the ISO of the CD copied to it.

[image: OpenFirmware Boot Screen]

I would like to give the FreeBSD partitions/drives (the first two icons in the picture) friendly names like the OS partitions/drives (the second two).  Even if I am limited to 11 characters, `FBSD10-INST` or something similar would be much better than having nothing.

The goal here is that if the user boots into this Open Firmware boot menu (holding <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> when booting, they will intuitively know what they are selecting.

Comment: The labels given by the FreeBSD tools you mention work *within FreeBSD*. Probably OS-X nor OpenFirmware know how to handle them.